# Linking a lib project that references a dll file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I have a c++ solution in VS2015 which contains two project ts (an Engine and a Game). The Game is a .exe has a dependency with the Engine, which is a .lib. The Engine references some symbols from 3rd party DLLs.

I've been trying to set up my project, but I can't get the Game to compile. It complains, at linker stage, that it can't find the symbols from the DLLs ("unsresolved external symbol X").

How do I set this up?

Comment: "references some symbols" does not mean anything.  If you did not merge the DLL's import library into Engine.lib then your Game project must link the import library as well.  Using #pragma comment(lib, "somedll.lib") is a simple way to embed a link instruction with code.

Comment: That was it. Solution configuration is not my strongest suit, so I forgot about that... The Engine project used to be an executable (now I'm decoupling the Game from it) and linked properly, so I went back to a previous version, copied the old lib references and put it in the new project. Thanks!